# php integer variable pass in mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to pass  php integer variable in mysql query?

like `$g = 44 ;`

```
$sql="
    SELECT
        idtransactiondetails,
        idtransactionmaster,
        T.idacledger,
        acledgername,
        transactionamount,
        chequeno 
    from transactiondetails T,
         acledger L 
    where 
        T.idacledger=L.idacledger 
        and idtransactionmaster=int()$g";
```

but in case `$g` its not working .

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained, are [officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp) and can be [dangerous in live code](http://bit.ly/4zUdtT). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: he hasn't even mentioned here he is using mysql_* functions. What is the point of telling it here!

Comment: @raheelshan If you're executing **the exact same code as you would in MySQL console**, like OP is, then you're not using prepared statements, protection from SQL injection, parametrised queries and therefore it's quite clear that OP is indeed using mysql_* - if you don't believe me, ask him ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql="SELECT idtransactiondetails,idtransactionmaster,T.idacledger,acledgername,transactionamount,chequeno from transactiondetails T,acledger L where T.idacledger=L.idacledger and idtransactionmaster="`.$g;`
```

Comment: thanks for helping we are not forwarding $g as function on it so it work properly ....thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$sql="SELECT idtransactiondetails,idtransactionmaster,T.idacledger,acledgername,transactionamount,chequeno from transactiondetails T,acledger L where T.idacledger=L.idacledger and idtransactionmaster=$g";
```

Answer (score 0):

[Concatenate](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) the string:

```
    $sql = "SELECT idtransactiondetails, idtransactionmaster, T.idacledger, acledgername, transactionamount, chequeno 
FROM transactiondetails T, acledger L 
WHERE T.idacledger = L.idacledger 
AND idtransactionmaster=" . (int) $g. ";";
```

Comment: Are you sure about `int()`, that's php here ;-)

Comment: Whoops, wrong type cast. Corrected :)

Answer (score 0):

not need to use int in Query,

```
$sql="SELECT idtransactiondetails,idtransactionmaster,T.idacledger,acledgername,transactionamount,chequeno from transactiondetails T,acledger L where T.idacledger=L.idacledger and idtransactionmaster= $g ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Confirms your variable contains integer value if you are trying to avoid sql injections & all

```
$g = "50'a+_)(*&^%$#@!";
$integer = intval($g); // 50
$sql = "SELECT idtransactiondetails,idtransactionmaster,T.idacledger,acledgername,transactionamount,chequeno from transactiondetails T,acledger L where T.idacledger=L.idacledger and idtransactionmaster = '$integer'";
```