# Can´t pass integer in mysql query using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have the following php code:

```
<?php

$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "TISD";
$password = "conex2017";
$dbname = "45868972A-15473654J";

$year=$_POST['year'];
$yearInt=(int)$year;

// Create connection
$db=mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password) or die("Error in Mysql connection"); 


$result=mysql_db_query($dbname,"SELECT Titulo FROM Completa WHERE Año='".$yearInt."';",$db);


print("Listado de ejemplares para el anio dado:");
print("<BR>");
$contador = 0;

if($result === FALSE) { 
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $contador = $contador + 1;
  print ($contador);
  print (": ");
  print($row["Titulo"]);
  print("<BR>");
} 

mysql_close(); 

?>
```

This php receive a string variable named "year" from a form, I transform this into a int, name yearInt, (everything correct until here). When I execute the script I obtain the following error:

> Listado de ejemplares para el anio dado:
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '±o='1994'' at line 1

I have tried solution answered here [php integer variable pass in mysql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408546/php-integer-variable-pass-in-mysql-query), but it did not work for me.

%%%%  SOLUTION  %%%%

I have modified my database changing column "Año" to "Anio". It was due to character ñ.

Comment: is this `Año` your column name?

Comment: Stop using the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: You may want to start using English characters in programming

Comment: @AgamBanga Yes, column names are correct.

Comment: @MehdiBounya This is a project for a spanish subject, I'm sorry you dislike it hehe

Comment: you need to use the right collation for the db/table including an UTF8 declaration in the connection.

Comment: The `ñ` character is being interpreted as something `±` in your code

Comment: @Fred-ii- Actually i wanted to wrap the column name in string but was unable to do so

Comment: @AgamBanga It wouldn't have made a difference. The problem here is the db/table collation and UTF-8.

Comment: Ok; the question is starting to get answers that most likely won't solve this. I already said what the problem is here. I won't be able to add anything more to what I already said, and on more than one occasion.

Comment: Although you *can* use non-ASCII characters for column names, it's highly ill-advised. These can cause considerable frustration because people may not know how to type them, they might not have the right keyboard or know the short-cut to do it, plus their character set might not match. Using non-English column-names is fine. Accents, however, are **nothing but trouble**.

Answer (score 0):

try this it should work

```
$result=mysql_db_query($dbname,"SELECT Titulo FROM Completa WHERE Año=$year ;",$db);
```

You can remove the cast to int it has no meaning because you're casting a string to int and then int to string (the point between the string and the variable concatenate every thing to string)

Comment: I don't see how this would make a difference. MySQL will compensate for the quoted string. Did you not see the error here? `near '±o='1994''`

Comment: $year is a string you don't need to surround it with tow **'**

Comment: *"$year is a string you don't need to surround it"* - Year is `1994`, again.. MySQL in this case *will* compensate for that. There are instances where quoting it could affect it, but take my word for it; this isn't the case here.

Comment: give it a try you don't have any thing to lose

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the query as

```
SELECT Titulo FROM Completa WHERE `Año`='".$yearInt."';
```

Notice the backticks for the column name.

Comment: I don't think this will make much of a difference, but the OP can try it.

Comment: I'm guessing escaping the column name might make mysql to interpret the name correctly.

Comment: You could be right to a certain extent. Yet, the OP seems to have left; probably trying to fix it themselves, or Googling, or "I don't know". They haven't responded to my comments, or the answers given. I told them what the (most likely) cause to the problem is. Maybe they're waiting on "me" to provide them with a full solution, I don't know.

Comment: I agree using the correct collation is the correct way to go. Mine was a quick fix. Maybe they do want a better solution from you :)